# Buddypress members area in blank in my live server

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, buddypress

Buddypress member area is showing blank in my live server but it is showing fine in my localhost. I have tried debugging it is not showing any bug. how can i get the members area back live.

I am using a windows server with PHP 5.6 and WordPress 4.9.8

Comment: Hey there, it seems you are making a statement, but I'm missing the question. Perhaps have a look at this! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Where is the code you are having issues with?

Comment: its in live server. the code with local host is working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the URL for the members list.

Localhost URL are not case sensitive but server URL are.

eg.

> **URL:** abc.com/xyz/test.php
>
> **URL you keep in your code:** abc.com/XYZ/test.php
>
> **abc.com/XYZ/test.php** Works in local but fails on server